# Ionic on a web server

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an ionic 3 app. It builds and runs on Android and iOS as expected. Usually the app can be tested in a browser by executing **`ionic serve`** shell command and then navigating to **`http://localhost:8100/`** URL in the browser.

But is there a way to deploy this ionic app to a web browser as a platform, so it could be later deployed to a web server and be publicly available?

Answer (score 3):

You can add `browser` as a platform, then build it and copy the `/www` folder on your webserver.

1. `ionic platform add browser` (or if using ionic-cli v3 `ionic cordova platform add browser`)
2. `ionic build browser --prod` (or if using ionic-cli v3 `ionic cordova build browser --prod`)
3. Copy files from the `/www` folder to your webservers root directory.

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try.